# Export Email from Thunderbird to Microsoft Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, export

Export Mail from Thunderbird to Microsoft Outlook

There is no default export feature in the application

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/et_export_to_oe.htm) About.com How-To article gives step by step instructions on exporting mail to another application. You need an application called [mbx2eml](http://email.about.com/od/outlookexpressaddons/gr/mbx2eml.htm) however this is an extremely painful and manual process.

I am not sure if there is any add-ons available that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This approach definitely is not for the weak-hearted, though it is not as hard as it may seem at first.** It does require some (guided) command line inputs and a basic understanding of troubleshooting, as there are some (minor) parameters that could go wrong and that then would need either common sense or a quick online search.

As far as I can see, there is nothing in this answer that could prove harmful to your e-mails: **If, at some point, you decide that it is too hard for you, take a deep breath, read through the whole answer twice, and see if you can do it, then.** If you still think it is too hard, then you can abort the process at any given point and/or uninstall any suggested programs - and not a single one of your mails will be missing.

---

I want to share my solution with the latest version of Thunderbird (52.9.1) and Microsoft Office Outlook 2016 to get local mails (received via POP3 by Thunderbird) into a `.PST`-file (so POP3 on Outlook, too).

**Basically, it uses an IMAP-server of your choice as an intermediate storage for your e-mails.** I tried to automate the process as much as possible, while making it as reliable as possible. It still is a semi-manual process that takes some time (around 1 hour for 20 folders and 15 000 mails / 2.5 GiB), but in my experience, **it works very reliably, it does not harm your existing e-mails, and it is still using free, mostly open-source tools.**

---

#### Requirements:

- **A working Python (v2) environment**. I chose to use [Windows Subsystem for Linux (requires Win10) and Debian 9.4](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/wsl/install-win10), but [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/) might work just as well.
- [**ImportExportTools** from Mozilla's add-on site](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/). In Thunderbird, go to `Add-Ons`, press the cogwheel-button and select `Install xpi`. Select the `.xpi`-file, restart Thunderbird.
- [Some version of **imap-upload**](https://github.com/navneetkarnani/imap-upload). (I chose the linked fork because it works the best in my experience.)
- **A working IMAP server**. Gmail works fine, but to speed things up, I chose to use a local IMAP server (no up- and download via the ISP, no file size limit, no security settings to change,...), which in my case was [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/download/).

---

#### Step-by-step guide:

1. *Maybe set ImportExportTools' settings, such as the maximum length of headers.* Then, export each folder with `ImportExportTools -> Export Folder`. You can select multiple folders at once. <sup>Note: I did choose to export in a non-recursive fashion because recursive files gave me problems later on with their encoding.</sup>
2. (Optional) set up hMailServer. I  used [Peter Kellner's guide "How To Setup Your Own Pop3/IMAP Email Server for Local Development Testing"](http://peterkellner.net/2012/03/11/how-to-setup-your-own-pop3imap-email-server-for-local-development-testing/). Basically, you need to setup a domain (e.g. `mail.local`) that also neds to be set in your [`hosts`-file](https://superuser.com/questions/525688/whats-the-windows-equivalent-of-etc-hosts). Then, add an account to the domain, set your domain as default, maybe increase the size limit, and disable auto-ban.
3. Upload the exported files with imap-upload: `python .\imap-upload.py .\INBOX --gmail` for Gmail or `--host=mail.local --user=YOUR_USER@mail.local --password=YOUR_PASSWORD` for your local IMAP server. You can also play around with `--box` and add folders for each folder-file. Please note that if you want to keep your folder structure, you either have to use the `--box` parameter or you will have to upload one file at a time, then go to the next step, then go back to this step, repeat.
4. In Outlook, set up a `.PST`-file (if you do not have one already) and set up and link your `mail.local`-account to it. If you used `--box`, use IMAP, else use POP3. Both the POP3 and the SMTP address are `mail.local`. Set it up to delete the e-mails from the server after downloading them.

   - For POP3: Press `Send/Receive` and wait until all e-mails are downloaded. Then, move them to a new folder (if necessary).
   - For IMAP: Press `Send/Receive` and wait. Then, you can drag'n'drop the folders to your local mailbox.
5. Check if all went well by looking at imap-upload's output and by comparing the number of mails between Thunderbird and Outlook. imap-upload usually Tells you if something went wrong, but I usually take some random samples of attachments and mails to see if all went well.

Comment: It looks like you put a lot of effort into perfecting this, so kudos.  But it doesn't look like a very practical solution for your average user.  Just sayin'.

Comment: @fixer1234 For your average computer user, this is most certainly true. They might be better of paying a fee for some program (or hoping the trial works well) or using another new e-mail client in the first place. But for everyone that is a bit above-average (i.e. people brave enough to at least try command line tools), this might be a no-brainer compared to the 60$-ish programs you find in your favorite search engine that won't do the task any better (or so I think). The biggest problem I faced was to get from ["use IMAP"](https://superuser.com/a/1124836/703240) to a reliable process.

Comment: @fixer1234 I added a header to warn/inform users of the needed experience - and also motivate them to try it, still, as I still think that getting something for free while having the ability to learn something is a nice way to spend your evening. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [MBOX to PST Converter](http://www.ktoolssoftware.com/convert-mbox-to-pst.html) and reportedly you can use [Mailstore Home](http://www.mailstore.com/de/mailstore-home.aspx) for this as well. I haven't tried them, though.