# Importing e-mails from thunderbird to outlook 2007?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, export

IS there a better solution then what is offered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/16828/export-email-from-thunderbird-to-microsoft-outlook) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to get the mail items into a format that Outlook understands (eml) You might take a look at [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Export_mail_into_Outlook_(Express)_or_Apple_Mail) Mozillazine kb article, it lists various utilities for performing the conversion process.

In the past I had to do this for a customer and I used [ImportExportTools](https://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html) which is listed on the aforementioned page, not great, not fast, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this using Thunderbird 3, Outlook Express 6 and Outlook 2003, but I hope it can help anyone else who's reading this QA.

In Thunderbird:

- CTRL+A to select all messages
- right-click & Save As
- save all the messages inside a folder (it saves as .eml files)

Open Outlook Express

- drag all the eml files that you save earlier into Outlook Express

Open Outlook

- click Import in the drop-down menu
- choose Import from another program or file
- choose Outlook Express