# Moving email from Thunderbird to Outlook

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2016

IS there a quick and easy way to move 3 years worth of emails from Thunderbird to Outlook 2016?

The email is setup as POP3.

So far my only idea has been to create or some how setup the same account as IMAP let the emails sync back up and then let them sync back down in Outlook.

Sounds painful but I am trying to avoid spending money on an application that may or may not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your POP3 account (in Thunderbird) is configured to leave messages on server, then the best way is to setup the IMAP/POP3 account in Outlook and download messages. All other ways lead to using third-party apps.